# Installing Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm having trouble installing microsoft visual studio 2017. It loads to 100% then the setup fails. I get this error:

```
Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26711.1' failed to 
install.
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does your system meet the requirements for installation?  Are you allowed to install on the machine?  Have you looked the error up on microsofts support forums?

Comment: Yes I can install on the machine...it finish acquiring the packages but then applying the Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi it fails

Comment: Bro, Once I faced problem like this. You need to uninstall previous installations of previous version of VS. and remove package cache from "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages" Then try to install again with munimum modules.

Comment: if you failed then Reset your PC.

Comment: Uninstalling the previous version but it still give the error

Comment: Don't know my question put on hold. Wasn't it a legit question? The package and installer goes into two different folder and I'm not sure if that's the reason it keeps failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run installation as administrator. You need to have acces to folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\`.
Also check [this article](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24268/setup-operation-failed-microsoftvisualstudiominshe.html).

Comment: I have found the folder, do i move it?

Comment: How do you mean "move"? In the article above is part Solutions > Best solution, just follow it.

Comment: The package and installer goes into two different folder and I'm not sure if that's the reason it keeps failing

Comment: Well, I still don't know what you mean, sorry. Just open command prompt as admin and type `takeown /f "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages" /r /d y` and `icacls "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages"  /grant administrators:F /t`, then run VS 2017 installatin as admin.

Comment: ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages, The packages folder are stored here while installer and 2017 folders are stored in peogramfiles. Wondering if that should be the case

Comment: I think that doesn't matter. Programs have their stuff in many folders (eg. C:\Program Files, C:\ProgramData, C:\Users\username\AppData).

Comment: I still don't know if you tried that link in my answer. There is a section Solutions.

Comment: It still failed

Comment: what else could be the reason

Comment: It's saying it can' install `Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26711.1`. So, do you have folder `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=15.0.26711.1`? If yes, what files are there? I have there _package.json, cab1.cab, Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.msi.

Comment: I got it to work what you gave along with anti virus was blocking it

Comment: Oh yeah, congrats!